# angular styles doesn't work after rebuilding project

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

After rebuilding my project, police changed, nav item in the nav-bar don't display correctly, modal witdh don't work. What happened:

[image]

Comment: angular version ?

Comment: also how did you import bootstrap to the project did you add `@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` to style.css after `npm install --save bootstrap`

Comment: angualr version is 6.0.3

Comment: I did npm install --save bootstrap,                                                                                 And add "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],                                                                                                                     to angular.json file